# Order on second degree relationship in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models in a many-to-many relationship: `Fixture` and `Event`.

**Fixture:**

```php
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'fixture_events')->withPivot('player_id');
}
```

**Event:**

```php
public function fixtures()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Fixture::class, 'fixture_events')->withPivot('player_id');
}
```

You will notice that the pivot table has an additional field `player_id`. This is because **FixtureEvent** also had a relationship to a model called Player.

**FixtureEvent:**

```php
public function fixture()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Fixture::class, 'id', 'fixture_id');
}

public function event()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Event::class, 'id', 'event_id');
}

public function player()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Player::class, 'id', 'player_id');
}
```

**And Player has:**

```php
public function events()
{
    return $this->hasMany(FixtureEvent::class);
}
```

My problem arises when I want to get all the `fixture_events` for a player and sort them by a field in the `events` table. This field is named `sequence`.

However, whatever I do, the events always come out ordered by ID.

This is the query that I would like to order by `events.sequence`, whether by using some type of join or whatever works (this is inside the `Player` model so `$this` is a player object):

```php
$events = $this->events()->whereHas('fixture', function ($query) use ($round, $competition_id) {
    $query->where('fixtures.round', '=', $round)->where('competition_id', $competition_id);
})->get();
```

I've tried adding a join query here on `fixture_events.event_id = events.id` and then ordering by `events.sequence` but this doesn't work.

I've also tried adding `orderBy` directly in the model relationship, i.e. in the **Fixture** model:

```php
public function events()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'fixture_events')->orderBy('sequence')->withPivot('player_id');
}
```

But this does nothing for my problem.

How do I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
At first I misread the relations, can you try with the below query?

```php
$events = $this->events()->whereHas('fixture', function ($query) use ($round, $competition_id) {
    $query->where('fixtures.round', '=', $round)->where('competition_id', $competition_id);
})->with(['events.event' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('sequence');
}])->get();
```

---

<strike>You have a couple of alternatives, but first I suggest you to edit your relationship to include the `sequence` field you are trying to load.</strike>

Then proceed with one of the following:

1. Order by on the relationship definition, but I think you have to load that field from the pivot table, otherwise you won't have its value, and prefix the relations table on the orderby field.

```php
public function events() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'fixture_events')
        ->withPivot(['player_id', 'sequence'])
        ->orderBy('fixture_events.sequence');
}
```

or with:

```php
public function events() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'fixture_events')
        ->withPivot(['player_id', 'sequence'])
        ->orderBy('pivot_sequence');
}
```

2. Order by a pivot field outside the relation can be done like this:

```php
$events = $this->events()->whereHas('fixture', function ($query) use ($round, $competition_id) {
    $query->where('fixtures.round', '=', $round)->where('competition_id', $competition_id);
})->with(['fixture' => function ($query) {
    $query->orderBy('sequence');
}])->get();
```

or with:

```php
$events = $this->events()->whereHas('fixture', function ($query) use ($round, $competition_id) {
    $query->where('fixtures.round', '=', $round)->where('competition_id', $competition_id);
})
->orderBy('pivot_sequence')
->get();
```

Let me know if any of these methods works!

Comment: Those are all very good suggestions, but I don't think you understood a vital part of my DB structure: the `sequence` field is in the `events` table, not in the `fixture_events` table. Any update with that in mind?

Comment: I noticed that after I posted the answer, but the first method should work anyways (ordering in the events relation), but you have to include the `sequence` field in the `withPivot` method, or you can't use its value.

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately. Also, I don't think the field should be included in the `withPivot` method since it's not in the pivot table but in the main `events` table?

Comment: I have updated my answer, can you please try that query? If not can you post a relevant example of your tables and a couple of records and the expected output?